# Непрерывное звучание при навигации по сайту

Tags: javascript, html5, history-api

Как сделать, чтобы при переходе по страницам сайта звук не прерывался?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пытался делать подобное через новую фичу HTML5 History API, но придётся так же написать js кода.

[Статья на хабре для знакомства](http://habrahabr.ru/post/123106/)

В статье так же есть ссылочка на страничку, где есть информация, какими браузерами поддерживается данная технология.

Кстати, есть информация, что vk использует данную технологию у себя, правда не проверял.
Удачи в начинаниях!

Answer (score 1):

Сделать сайт в виде одностраничного приложения. Если у вас уже большой сайт и вы не хотите всё целиком переписывать, можно попробовать сделать это с помощью iframe, растянутого на весь экран, в которой будет собственно сайт, + элемент которым вы издаете звук за его пределами. Т.е. переход по страницам сайта будет во фрейме, а звук - в странице контейнере, которая не будет перезагружаться. Но такой костыль принесет вам массу проблем

Comment: Можно попробовать не переписывать, а просто добавить умный обработчик ссылок и форм, который будет по XMLHttpRequest забирать страницы, которые сервер будет отдавать обёрнутые в json (если архитектура сервера сие позволит)

Comment: Ага. Это называется одностраничное приложение.

Comment: Обычно под одностраничным приложением имеют в виду ещё более умную вещь со своим MVC (или аналогом) и работой по нормальному API вместо передачи html-кода, но ладно.

Comment: А,вы имели ввиду сразу html передавать? А вы пробовали когда нибудь так делать? Я пробовал. Много проблем с применением js к полученному таким образом html

Comment: тут все зависит уже от конкретного сайта

Comment: Да, я себе такой сайт с аудиоплеером писал. С js проблемы, но если его мало и он не слишком умный, то скорее всего не проблема)